# How to expose Hystrix Stream on Spring Actuator port?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, hystrix

I am using Jetty embedded server in the Spring Boot application.

To handle requests I provide my custom handler like that.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Main.class).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizer(JettyRequestHandler myCustomHandler) throws MalformedURLException {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                    customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
                }
            }

            private void customizeJetty(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jetty) {
                jetty.addServerCustomizers((JettyServerCustomizer) server -> {
                    HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
                    handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[]{myCustomHandler, server.getHandler()});
                    server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I am listening for a requests on a standard `8080` port. I included also `Spring Boot Actuator` into my project to get some production endpoints (health, etc.).  It starts on another port: `8181`.

Additionally I am using Hystrix for circuit breaking purposes.

My question is how to enable Hystrix Stream to be exposed on actuator port?

Currently I managed only to expose it on standard port `8080` with following piece of code:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean hystrixStreamServlet(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new HystrixMetricsStreamServlet(), "/hystrix.stream");
}
```

But I would like to expose it on another, to have the default one only for application purposes.

Those are some of my dependecies:

```
compile 'com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:1.5.3'
compile 'com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:1.5.3' 
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.3.5.RELEASE'
```

I would like NOT to use Spring Cloud where is @EnableHystrix that gives the stream on the actuator port actually.

Comment: Why won't you use Spring Cloud? That already provides all that you request? You can at least look at the auto configuration of that component for inspiration (it is nothing more then some configuration around the netflix hysterix).

Answer (score 2):

Actually I did what @m-deinum proposed and it worked. I used Spring Cloud Stack.

To achieve Hystrix Stream on actuator I added dependecies:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter', version: '1.1.1.RELEASE'          // spring cloud starter
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-hystrix', version: '1.1.3.RELEASE'  // spring cloud hystrix starter
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-ribbon', version: '1.1.3.RELEASE'   // spring ribbon starter
```

And the annotation on the Main class:

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Main.class).run(args);
    }
    // ...
}
```